# How to configure for multiple siginin signiut url

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have provided multiple signin url  in cognito as comma separated but my local react ui has 1 of the them as signin url (ex- http://localhost:3000/,https//abc.com in cognito  and in my local UI I have only http://localhost:3000/  )  when I try to login it says url mismatch so it’s not forwarding to my application not sure how to provide in aws-amplify configuration file . Any input ?

Comment: I take it you are using the Cognito hosted UI? Please provide the URL you are setting for the LOGIN endpoint https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html

Comment: The URL takes the form 'GET https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?
response_type=code&
client_id=ad398u21ijw3s9w3939&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/redirect_uri&
state=STATE&
scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'

Comment: Thanks for the input . I have that setup the way you have written . It works when I have. Single url in cognito login url (in aws ) and that is localhost let’s say . But if I keep both localhost and some other url (let’s say for qa env) then redirect for login does not work as my react ui running on local has only localhost on the amplify confit file . There I am getting the issue

Comment: That sounds fine. In Cognito you specify the URLs that are allowed. In your frontend you specify just the one URL you actually want to use. Are you thinking your frontend needs to specify all of them? (it doesn't)

Comment: Hello , I tried that with multiple url comma separated in Cognito and a single URL in my amplify config ...i see it throws me redirect_mismatch when i login

Comment: That's not why you are getting that error. You must be sending a URL that is not in the list. Are they exactly the same, maybe you have a leading slash or have specified a different page?

Comment: Can you update your question, include a screen shot of the relevant cognito console, and the exact URL you are using in react.

Comment: it was a URL issue at my side in the React code ..Thanks @stu it helped .

Comment: Was it not the exact same URL or what was the error? I have the same issue and I am sure that the urls match. It works if I exclude the second one but I need it for local and prod environment...

Can you give me a hint what might have been your problem?

Answer (score 0):

New Cognito UI allows to add multiple URls more easily. Though if you will use Facebook, Google or other identity provider, they usually check for allowed redirect URL match too, something to be checked too.

[image]